# How to numerate(?) an indexed element with alphabet letters

Tags: c#, devexpress, bing-maps

I have the following code, I want to name the indexed elements of the waypoins[NodeIndex] like if NodeIndex==0 , then name it as "starting node : A"
if NodeIndex ==1, then "B", NodeIndex==2 as "C" and so on. I don't know how to do it.

```
string waypointString = "38.481713 , 27.088842 ; 38.477967 , 27.095194 ; 38.468979 , 27.109935 ; 38.473381 , 27.112424 ; 38.459930 , 27.090800 ;38.469622 , 27.075265 ; 38.455494 , 27.119999 ; 38.451671 , 27.114656 ; 38.469483 , 27.134998 ; 38.468074 , 27.085409";

        string[] Nodes = waypointString.Split(';');
        DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint[] waypoints = new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint[Nodes.Length];

        int NodeIndex = -1;

        foreach (string Node in Nodes)
        {

            string[] Coordinates = Node.Split(',');
            NodeIndex++;
            waypoints[NodeIndex] = new DevExpress.XtraMap.GeoPoint();
            waypoints[NodeIndex].Latitude = double.Parse(Coordinates[0].Trim());
            waypoints[NodeIndex].Longitude = double.Parse(Coordinates[1].Trim());

        }
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,GeoPoint>` ?

Comment: @EZI That helped a lot! Is there a way to assign them automatically? I mean like using i++ for int i ?

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(i++ + 'A').ToString()`

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Add an answer, self-answering is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EZI, the problem is solved by using `Dictionary<string,GeoPoint>`